# Scan directory and find files by pattern

Tags: iphone, ios

I need a function with params - startDir, fileMask, textPattern.

I need scan a directory tree starting from the first startDir, and find the first file containing a string textPattern, whose name corresponds to the mask file_mask.

Could someone give me steps to do this and what classes I should use... 
Thanks, ;)